# custom domain name per customer single page application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, dns

I want to give my customer the ability to create their own todos list app/web.

So, I thought they could register to my application, for instance:
http://mytodos-app.com/signup and provide all preferences such as theme, title, name...

Now i could use the url/router ability to get some unique identifier from the url and use the same app, but fetch data for each customer.

i.e: http://mytodos-app.com/todos/:someuniqeid

1) is it sounds ok? or are there better strategies for this scenario?

2) if it's ok, If I want to give them the ability to configure their own domain (like in shopify you get some dynamic domain yourname.shopify.com).

So, what is the most popular/professional way to do it? I want it to be easy to the customer. any suggestions?

Comment: As the question is written, it is very broad in scope(not a specific programming question, but several questions: dynamic configurations, dns, routes) and encourages opinion based answers(Avoid words like "most" and "better").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than the "cool factor", there is no benefit to using actual customized sub-domains.

You can synthesize the behavior by:

1. In DNS, set up a wildcard CNAME entry for `*.DOMAIN.com` to point to `www.DOMAIN.com`, be sure to buy a matching wildcard ssl/tls certificate.
2. Configure the web server to respond to all hostnames.
3. After user registration. SANITIZE the `username`(or whatever identifier) value.
4. Set an authorization cookie with the `domain=DOMAIN.com` option to force it not to
   be a host cookie.
5. Redirect to `username.DOMAIN.com`. Same server different name.
6. Check the cookie in the route to serve the correct pages. Just like
   you would with any login.
7. If there is no cookie, use the host information to populate the
   username portion of the login page, or display public todos?

Make sure any Javascript scripts hosted on the site and all internal links are loaded by relative addressing.

The technique is much safer than actually creating real subdomains.